# NSMutableString as var name?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, string

Say I have this code

```
NSMutableString *object;
[object setString:@"myVar"];
```

Later how can I use object as a var name?

ie...

```
[object.string someMethod];
```

where someMethod is called on the myVar object (which is the string text of object)

Is this possible?

Comment: Or you want to use the `NSMutableString` as parameter of a method ?

Comment: It is possible to use a string as a name of an object property, but it is not simple: see [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1) for the details.

Comment: If you could describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, there may be a much easier solution.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thank you, I thought KVC was the way to do it, but I hoped there might be a quicker method, please answer with KVC and I will mark you the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocoa lets you access properties and fields using [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1). If an `NSString` (mutable or not) has a name of a property, you can use that string to retrieve a value of the corresponding property from an object:

```
MyObject *myObj = ...
NSMutableString *varName;
[varName setString:@"myVar"];
[myObj valueForKey:varName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Probably you are looking for [NSClassFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) method.

If `someMethod` is a class method then you can use:

```
[NSClassFromString(object) performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```

Comment: Thanks, really I wanted to be able to substitute a string in a method call...  [myString someMethod] ....      Where myString can be changed to suit the variable I want called depending on the situation. I guess this is not possible.